# Implement new SHA256 signature for Redsys/Sermepa in Python

Tags: python, payment-gateway, sha256

I have a django-based application that uses Redsys (earlier Sermepa) as a credit card payment platform. Recently we have received a message that urge us to migrate from old SHA1 signatures to SHA256 in order to keep using the platform securely.

Platform provide several examples of how to make the new requests generating a new signature, but only using PHP and Java. Now I am trying to port the provided solutions to Python without success.

This is a sample working code in PHP (with fake key/data):

```
<?php
    // Init form with default data
    $order = "ABCDEFGHI";
    $merchant_parameters = array( 
        "DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT" => "1000",
        "DS_MERCHANT_ORDER" => strval($order) ,
        "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE" => "012345678",
        "DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY" => "978",
        "DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE" => "0",
        "DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL" => "1",
    ); 

    // Key definition, decoding, and encrypt using $order
    $key = 'Bg8HYhVT79PDvOxbI/Newcm31QY/9999';
    echo 'key --> ' , $key , '<br/><br/>';
    $key_decoded = base64_decode($key);
    echo 'key-decoded --> ' , $key_decoded , '<br/><br/>';
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key_decoded, $order, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,  implode(array_map("chr", array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))) );
    echo 'ciphertext --> ' , $ciphertext , '<br/><br/>';

    // Transform array in encoded json
    $parameters = json_encode($merchant_parameters);
    echo 'parameters --> ' , $parameters , '<br/><br/>';
    $parameters_encoded = base64_encode($parameters);
    echo 'parameters_encoded --> ' , $parameters_encoded , '<br/><br/>';

    // Calculate MAC256 of encoded array
    $mac_256 = hash_hmac('sha256', $parameters_encoded, $ciphertext, true);
    echo 'mac_256 --> ' , $mac_256 , '<br/><br/>';

    // Encode MAC256 in base64 to get the signature
    $mac_256_encoded = base64_encode($mac_256);
    echo 'mac_256_encoded --> ' , $mac_256_encoded , '<br/><br/>';
?>
```

And this is my equivalent code in Python, with the same fake data:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from pyDes import triple_des, CBC, PAD_PKCS5
import hashlib, json, base64, hmac
from json import JSONEncoder


# Init form with default data
order = "ABCDEFGHI"
merchant_parameters = {}
merchant_parameters['DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT'] = "1000"
merchant_parameters['DS_MERCHANT_ORDER'] = order
merchant_parameters['DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE'] = "012345678"
merchant_parameters['DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY'] = "978"
merchant_parameters['DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE'] = "0"
merchant_parameters['DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL'] = "1"


# Key definition, decoding, and encrypt using order
key = 'Bg8HYhVT79PDvOxbI/Newcm31QY/9999'
print '\n\nkey --> %s' % key
key_decoded  = base64.b64decode(key)
print '\n\nkey_decoded --> %s' % key_decoded
k = triple_des(key_decoded, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None,  padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
ciphertext  = k.encrypt(order)
print '\n\nciphertext --> %s' % ciphertext


#  Transform array in encoded json (with no lines
parameters = (json.dumps(merchant_parameters)).encode()
print '\n\nparameters --> %s' % parameters
parameters_encoded = ''.join(unicode(base64.encodestring(parameters), 'utf-8').splitlines())
print '\n\nparameters_encoded --> %s' % parameters_encoded


# Calculate MAC256 of encoded array
mac_256 = hmac.new(ciphertext, parameters_encoded, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print '\n\nmac_256 --> %s' % mac_256


# Encode MAC256 in base64 to get the signature
mac_256_encoded = base64.b64encode(mac_256)
print '\n\nmac_256_encoded --> %s' % mac_256_encoded
```

As can be seen if running the codes, resultant signatures are not equivalent, thus the payment platform rejects my Python request.

Can anybody notice where am I wrong regarding the signature generation?

Thanks in advance,
Álvaro.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem.

Actually, after JSON encoding I have had to clean the blank spaces between key/value pairs up.
But I am getting different signatures for the ciphertext. That causes that final signature is different from the examples.

Notice that in example code they do a trailing pad for order number in the 3DES encryption.

```
iv = b'\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'
k = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
ceros = b'\0'*(len(DS_MERCHANT_ORDER)%8)
clave = k.encrypt(DS_MERCHANT_ORDER+ceros.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Thanks

EDITED:

Finally I fixed it:

To get the specific per operation key:

```
    iv = b'\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'
    k = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
    ceros = b'\0'*(len(DS_MERCHANT_ORDER)%8)
    claveOp = k.encrypt(DS_MERCHANT_ORDER+ceros.encode('UTF-8'))
```

To get the hmac.sha256:

```
    from Crypto.Hash import HMAC, SHA256
    # Realizo la codificacion SHA256
    dig = HMAC.new(claveOp , msg=DS_MERCHANT_PARAMETERS,    digestmod=SHA256).digest()
    signatureEnc = base64.b64encode(dig)
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi Rafa,  we have made some progress in the following django module, it may help you https://github.com/alvarovelezgalvez/django-sermepa

Answer (score 1):

Hie,
finally I publish in pypi new version about redsys client. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redsys/

Thanks Álvaro about to do sha256 signature.